# translate3d vs css left/top and hardware acceleration

Tags: javascript, jquery, translate3d

As I understand hardware acceleration on iOS devices is enabled when using translate3d(). So why [this test on jsperf](http://jsperf.com/translate3d-vs-xy/4) shows that using css left/top is faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used `translate3d` extensively on iOS in lieu of CSS left/top, and I can say one thing:

It is truly faster for *animating* things (which *jsperf* does not seem to do.) My guess is, left/top is faster when benchmarking since nothing is animated and I don't think anything is displayed either.

It is when used in conjunction with `transition` (or `-webkit-transition`) that `translate3d` works its magic.